# How to change cross country ski bindings

Tags: equipment, skiing, cross-country-skiing

I bought used cross country skis that have SNS Pilot bindings on them, and I also bought NNN boots. What equipment do I need to swap the SNS bindings for NNN bindings? And how do I do it?

I've searched the web, and I found many results about how to mount bindings on new skis, but I couldn't find any instructions for swapping bindings on used skis.

In particular, if there is epoxy, do I need a solvent to release the epoxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not recommended to change the attacks on cross-country skis.

The holes of sns attacks ("Salomon") are in a different position from the attacks nnn ("Rottefella"), then you should first fill the holes with cylindrical woods plugs (watch out the dimensions) and glue.

After the ski is like the original situation you can mount new bindings.

For epoxy resin now there are solutions to be used even without solvent, only after it is mounted leave it to dry for a long time in hot, dry conditions

Obviously if you can go to a professional you have more possibility to get a well done job

Answer (score 1):

Salomon (and others?), as of 2016, makes NNN compatible bindings (and boots) under the "ProLink" name in addition to their SNS offerings. I believe that ProLink bindings have the same mounting screw holes as SNS bindings, so that might be an easier option than filling screw holes.

See http://xcskiforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=4865 for some discussion and this note from Atomic https://www.atomic.com/en/sns-bindings